# How to fix: You have macOS 10.14.6. The application requires macOS 11.0 or later?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have written an app on my MacBook Pro, with macOS 11.1. Now I want to send the app to someone else, who's MacBook only has macOS 10.14.6. When he tries to launch the app, he gets the error: "You have macOS 10.14.6. The application requires macOS 11.0 or later" I have already set the Deploymenttarget of the Project and the Targets to below 10.14.

[image]

Comment: Most likely you will need to change the deployment version in the target's build settings and make a new build.

Comment: What kind of project did you create? Did you use SwiftUI for the user interface? SwiftUI apps won't run on macOS 10.14 no matter what you set for the deployment target. If you select the project file from the project navigator, you can set the deployment target for the project from there.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk yeah that is the problem. didn't think about that. When I changed the deployment target a lot of errors popped up. Since I used swiftui.